# Google search via AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I would like to make a Google search with an AppleScript. The code looks like this:

```
set search to text returned of (display dialog "Google Search" buttons {"OK"} default answer {""})
open location ("https://www.google.de/#q=" & search)
```

The problem is, how can I change the spaces to a `+`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a subroutine for replacing characters:

> ```
> on replace_chars(this_text, search_string, replacement_string)
>   set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the search_string
>   set the item_list to every text item of this_text
>   set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the replacement_string
>   set this_text to the item_list as string
>   set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
>   return this_text
> end replace_chars
> ```

<sup>Source: http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/sbrt/sbrt-06.html</sup>

Between those two lines of AppleScript, insert the following:

```
set search to replace_chars(search," ","+")
```